# How can you conditionally swap out a dropdown on a range of cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to work on a sheet that allows me to switch between a true/false value and based on that result it toggles between 2 different dropdown options in another cell.

**Desired Result**

---

- Cell C2 contains a dropdown of TRUE/FALSE
- Cells H2/J2/L2 contain a dropdown that is also dependent on the value specified by the C2 dropdown.
- H2/J2/L2 get the data from 2 separate sheets.
- Solution scales infinitely based on the corresponding row in the C column IE if it's C3 then the logic needs to apply to H3/J3/L3, etc.

**Example**

---

I have the sample spreadsheet that I'm working on [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wvELYt2UkleBpE1y8JqsyY0XeFgu26QHf3O_a8IR7XQ/edit#gid=1736361601).

- C2 is pulling the data from the MISC sheet for a boolean value
- H2/J2 need to pull the data from B10-B27 on either `GS256 OR GS256 Classified`
- L2 needs to pull the data from B28-B36 on either `GS256 OR GS256 Classified`

  - GS256 contains the data if C2 is set to FALSE and GS256 Classified contains the data if C2 is set to TRUE.
- I want to be able to handle variable amounts of values if for instance more values are added or subtracted on each of the corresponding one.

**What I've tried**

---

I've tried to do a mix of to using `ArrayFormula` with an if statement, however the issue that I face here is that it's dependent on a single cell, and it swaps the data in the multiple places, not just the single cell that I want to impact. So this effectively is just setting the drop downs to a single dataset.

Looking for feedback on how to approach this. All the data I'm getting from an external source via `ImportRange`. I'm fairly new to using sheets, but understand the basics. If I need to add a script I'm fine doing so since I'm more of a programmer. If this would be better served via a different interface like a web app then I'm fine doing so since this seems like this might be fairly complex with the variability of the data I'm working with on the spreadsheet.

Comment: @I'-'I I want to be able to account for different data in the same range across different sheets.

Comment: yeah that data is subject to change, so want to be able to account for that potential change.

Answer (score 1):

```
function dataValidation() {                                                                                     
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                                                             
var Tr = ss.getRange("'Body Armor'!C1:C20").getValues(); //Testrange
// Variables and sheetnames
        var b = "'Body Armor'!";                                                                        
        var g = "GS256!" ;
        var gC = "'GS256 Classified'!";
        var h = "B10:B27";
        var l = "B28:B36";
// Get DV ranges
        var gh = ss.getRange(g+h) ;                                                                     
        var ghc = ss.getRange(gC+h);
        var gl = ss.getRange(g+l);                                                                      
        var glc = ss.getRange(gC+l);
// Build DV rules
        var ghr = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(gh,true);
        var ghcr = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(ghc,true);
        var glr = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(gl,true);
        var glcr= SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(glc,true);
// Loop through each cell
        for(i=0;i<Tr.length;i++) {
                var j = i+1;
                var Hr = ss.getRange(b+"H"+j);
                var Jr = ss.getRange(b+"J"+j);
                var Lr =  ss.getRange(b+"L"+j);
// Test the test range and apply corresponding DV
        if (Tr[i][0] == true) {
                Hr.setDataValidation(ghcr);
                Jr.setDataValidation(ghcr);
                Lr.setDataValidation(glcr);
                }
                else {
                Hr.setDataValidation(ghr);
                Jr.setDataValidation(ghr);
                Lr.setDataValidation(glr);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm having issue with this calling when I updated C*. I tried adding an `onOpen()` and then calling the function, but that doesn't catch the edit event, so I tried making the called function from `onOpen` be `onEdit`, which just calls  `dataValidation`. `onOpen` I'm just adding a menu item to run the script. This is the code that I have added via the Script Editor - https://pastebin.com/pEuYKPwU. Is there a way to trigger the validation update when C* is edited? IE toggled between TRUE/FALSE. There is a difference between the 2 sheets on B19 in terms of data values.

Comment: I also tried executing it from `=dataValidation()` within the sheet itself, however since it's calling `setDataValidation()` it says permission denied even though the script executes fine and doesn't ask to grant permissions when I change the `onOpen` to use `dataValidation` instead. Any thoughts on how to get around that?

Comment: So I updated the code to be more in-line with what you were saying, but added a `e != undefined` check because the event doesn't exist unless a edit event has been triggered. I also went into the Edit menu and used the "current project's triggers" option, however when I run the script nothing takes place when an edit event has fired. I made sure to set the onEdit to use the `onEdit` function, however that's not doing anything. Updated pastebin - https://pastebin.com/AFakbWcH also I have an onOpen mapped to the `onOpen` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73427/discussion-between-elias-and-i-i).